# XML for Analysis parser: The restriction version is not recognized by the server

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, ssas-2012

### TITLE: Query Designer

I've just started to teach myself SSAS.  I am using SSDT 2015 with a 2012 database.  I've created my first cube and I've been able to process and deploy the cube as well as view the metadata (measures and dimensions).  I have also gone to properties and set the deployment server to  version 11.0. I am also able to log into the analysis server via ssms. But I keep getting the following message when trying to execute a query. I've attached a screen shot of the error. From the message, it seems that that parser does not under stand the VERSION. What is interesting is that when I log on the to SSAS server and go to the cube, I am able to browse and query the cube with no problem.  So it seems to be an issue with SSDT 2015

Query generation failed.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

XML for Analysis parser: The restriction, VERSION, is not recognized by the server. (Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Analysis Services)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I went back to basics and executed @@Version on the MSSQL server.  I saw that only Service Pack 1 had been installed.  So I downloaded SP 4 and installed it on the Sql Server.  I refreshed the connection and then reprocessed the cube.  I can now query the cube via SSDT.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. 
I deleted Encrypt = yes from my connection string than it worked.